# Getting a internal server error 500 while trying to call insert values from javascript into sql server in visual studio

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a code in javascript which calls a webmethod in c-sharp ,the javascript code and web method are given below

javascript code:

```
var _data = {

            '_mStart': document.getElementById("St_Period").value,
            '_mEnd': document.getElementById("En_Period").value
        };

                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "maps.aspx/myFunc",
                      data: _data,
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function(msg) {
                        alert("success!")
          }

        });
```

WEB method:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static void myFunc(DateTime? _mStart, DateTime? _mEnd)
    {

        try
        {

            SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("server=SWAPPS_LAP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=moogle;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveresultSets=true");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into MEDIA_BOOKING(ST_PERIOD,END_PERIOD,ENTERED_BY,ENTERED_ON) values(@st,@end,@by,@on)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st", _mStart);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", _mEnd);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@on", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

but when I run the code I get an error as

```
POST http://localhost:50060/moogle/maps.aspx/myFunc 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:8102
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send jquery.js:8102
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7580
savebook maps.aspx:398
onclick
```

I have a hunch maybe there is something wrong with the paramenters ,maybe they are not in the proper format?

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing a value for the `@by` parameter. Try adding a breakpoint in the catch statement to see what the error is. If you don't get to that stage the try posting the request body so that people can see what the request is and answer with more idea of the details.

Comment: yeah my bad ,I forget to clearr that field ,the error persist even after the correction,the request body?

Comment: @Snedden27 Could you include the information that is being sent to the server? Could you get any exception information from debugging? What is the format of the date values?

Comment: I interact with server using sql connection con mention above,and the cmd(insert cmd which is also mention)....I tried debuggin funny thing is now the code doesn't reach the myFunc even after the click event is triggered.....the date format is  dd/mm/yyyy which I am entering correctly......

Comment: Do you have a different locale on your server than your development machine? E.g. `en-us` on the server which would not recognise the `dd/mm/yyyy` format correctly.